# Android ListView and EditView on AlertDialog crash

Tags: java, android

I test my application on debug and crash on this line:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList);
```

with this error:
System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

---

I solved this error whit this code (change this with context):
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(promptsView.getContext(), R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList);
And change on XML file "EditView" with "EditText"!*

---

I have this layout for the items "editText_for_listview.xml":

```
<EditView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rowEditView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:textSize="16sp">
</EditView>
```

And my main layout "items_listview.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <ListView
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/mylistview"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code is this:

```
public void _ShowItems(String sTitle,android.content.Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(sTitle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    final View promptsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_listview, null);

    ListView mainListView ;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    mainListView = (ListView) promptsView.findViewById( R.id.editText_for_listview );

    String[] planets = new String[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    builder.setView(promptsView)
            .setPositiveButton("One", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Two", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}
```

Can you help me?
Where I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: where do you have that line of code before `onCreate` ?

Comment: Where did you call _ShowItems() method? I guess it's called before Activity.onCreate() is called.

Comment: I resolve this issue with this code: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList); Now not crash but the AlertDialog don't show!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are trying to use the Activity Context prior to the Activity's onCreate() method being called. Try moving your call to _ShowItems() to onResume() method.

Comment: I resolve this issue with this code: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList); Now not crash but the AlertDialog don't show!

Answer (score 0):

Could you show up more code of your activity. You could just be calling the method in a spot where the context isn't initialized but something else could be going on that will be revealed once we have a better look at the activity.

I would have made this a comment but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: I resolve this issue with this code: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.cd_edittext_for_listview, planetList); Now not crash but the AlertDialog don't show!